# How to handle a heterogeneous List with GSon

Tags: java, gson

I want to store something like

```
ImmutableList<Fruit> list =
    ImmutableList.of(new Orange(42), new Banana(43), new Apple("green"), new Apple("red"));
```

using GSon. Obviously I need to modify the serialization, as there's no way to recreate the List from the default output

```
[{"value":42},{"value":43},{"color":"green"},{"color":"red"}]
```

Adding a field "type" together with a custom Deserializer would probably do, but before trying I'd like to ask if there's a better way.

Comment: If you don't want to use a custom Deserializer, you may use a specific class having both fields. I know I construct my json classes directly for the needs of my json exchange. So those classes aren't the one of my main Business Object Model but that's simpler to manage and well isolated.

Comment: For the shown part of the problem, this is a nice solution I'm gonna implement. However, some of my "fruits" may contain other ones, so I need something else. Maybe it's really as simply as adding a virtual field `$class` with value obtained by `getClass().getName()` in the Serializer und using it in the Deserializer?

Comment: You can do that, or try to mix a not too heterogeneous tree with multipotent object (I mean with a little more than minimal fields) in order to keep the simplicity of json/gson.